# SharePoint GetListItems Return Keys Inconsistent

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss

When I call the SharePoint `GetListItems` web method, it returns some of the items with a GUID as the key, and the rest with a text ID as the key.

For example, if I have a form library with three columns, say `UserName`, `EnvironmentName`, and `LastStatus`, they might be returned as follows:

> ows_b5acede2_x002d_ab94_x002d_470f_x002d_b9e9_x002d_cdf4d3fe4e01=\"John Doe\" ows_EnvironmentName=\"Windows\"
>   ows__x0032_ef676c4_x002d_8f1c_x002d_4287_x002d_97c2_x002d_0d05ef782b83=\"Submitted\"

Why is it returning the column key as a GUID in some cases and how can I force it to return the text ID?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the InternalName of these columns is set to the Guid.

You can use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com) on the server to look at how everything is set up (there is both 2007 and 2010 versions)

Comment: Good point, SharePoint Manager does indeed show the internal name to be a GUID.  But I still wonder how it got to be that way since it's not the case for every column.

Comment: The InternalName is set when the column is created and can't be changed. Do you know how the coulmns was created?